# Auto-update JTable that is populated using a List<T>

Tags: java, swing, jtable

The program will allow the user to make a search. 
The search result is shown in a JTable.
The user can select a roW and hit a button called "edit" to do some editing on that certain "item".

Once the info are edited and he hits ok, the jtable is not being updated.

table before editing:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/unRTk.jpg]

user clicks on the button "edit" and edits the last field
JTable still showing the old info, it's not being updated

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmxd8.jpg]

Here's the code:

```
public void panelTable(){
    panelTable = new JPanel()
    panelTable.setSize(400, 80);
    panelTable.setOpaque(true);
    table =  new JTable();
    modele  = new DefaultTableModel();
}

public String getData(int colonNb ,int index){
     String dataTab = data[colonNb][index] + "";

    return dataTab;
}


public void creerJTable(List<Pneu> liste){
    String[] head= {"A", "B", "c"};
    this.liste = liste;


    data = new Object[liste.size()][3];
    Iterator<Pneu> it = liste.iterator();
    int index = 0;

    while(it.hasNext()){
        Pneu unPneu = it.next();
        data[index][0] = unPneu.construireDecription();
        data[index][1] = unPneu.getPrix();
        data[index][2] = unPneu.getNombrePneus();
        index++;
    }


    modele.setDataVector(data, head);
    table.setModel(modele);
    table.setRowSelectionInterval(0, 0);
    componentScroll(data,head);

    nbSearch++;
}


public void componentScroll(Object[][] data, String[] head){
    if(nbSearch <= 0){
        table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 80));
        table.setModel(modeleColonnesNoEdit(data, head));

        table.setRowSelectionInterval(0, 0);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(250);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setResizable(false);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(50);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setResizable(false);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(50);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 60));

        panoTab.add(scrollPane);
    }   
}

private DefaultTableModel modeleColonnesNoEdit(Object[][] data, String[] head) {

    return new DefaultTableModel(data, head)
    {

        boolean[] columnEditables = new boolean[] { false, false, false};

        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
            return columnEditables[column];
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: So far, you've not asked a question

Comment: The question is there but you have to read carefully:

Once the info are edited and he hits ok, the jtable is not being updated.

Comment: Nope, I don't see a `?` anywhere, all I see is *"The program will..."*, *"Once the info...*" which are statements. But if you like been crypt about these things, then I wish you luck finding an answer

Comment: Perhaps I am just missing it, but I do not see any code here that supports editing.

Comment: @KevinO Correct, this is the code for the table. the editing is done in a different class.

Comment: It is a bit strange that since the problem has to do, one presumes, with what happens *after an edit* that the code to actually perform the edit would not be needed. Nonetheless, did you try calling `table.revalidate()` after you made the edits?

Comment: @KevinO Let's just appreicate that `revalidate` has nothing to do with updating the table based on the changes to the model

Comment: @MadProgrammer, fair enough. Then fire a table changed event from the model. I apologize that I didn't read the Javadocs for revalidate closely; I saw it, and thought it was a close equivalent to the SWT methods that cause a view to requery its content provider. My bad.

Comment: @KevinO Well it's hard to tell from the iOS code, but they making multiple tables, which freaks me out and DefaultTableModel is capable of generating TableEvents, assuming you use it right and calling setModel would cause the ui to be update it's impossible to know what should be done. But, let's not forget that it's the models responsibility to trigger the TableEvents internally ;)

Comment: @KevinO problem fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by calling again the method creerJTable and passing it the new List !

It was one line of code something like that :
creerJTable(uneListe);

Thank you for your effort guys!